# Serialization of Dynamic JSON using ProtoBuf - Java

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers, jsonserializer, json-serialization

Need some insights: How to write proto file for serializing a java POJO class containing JSONObject as attribute with Protobuf serialization.
The JSON we have is fluid (keys keep changing).

Sample:

```
public class POJO {
 private String atr1;
 private long atr2;
 private Map<String, String> atr3;
 private JSONObject atr4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No proper apporach to handle such scenarios. However, JSON with java has fallback serialization default mechanism which is only option left with.